# Automatically updating QDateTimeEdit so that it displays the current system date and time

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

Using the Qt library, is there a way to automatically update a `QDateTimeEdit` using a signal such that the widget shows the current date and time in a similar fashion to a clock?

In the code sample below, `dateTimeEditSystem` is the `QDateTimeEdit` object.  However, the `setDateTime()` function only operates once. I would like the `QDateTimeEdit` object to dynamically update.  Is there a reliable way of doing this without using a timer (i.e. with signals and slots)?  Or is a timer the only way of doing this?

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    // setup the UI
    ui->setupUi(this);
    // set the current date and time
    ui->dateTimeEditSystem->setDateTime( QDateTime::currentDateTime() );
}
```

I tried using a timer, but unfortunately the `QDateTimeEdit` did not update.  Here is the complete mainwindow.cpp code.  What am I doing wrong here?

```
#include <QTimer>

#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->dateTimeEditSystem->setDateTime( QDateTime::currentDateTime() );

    QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT( updateTime() ));
    timer->start(1000);
}

void MainWindow::updateTime()
{
    ui->dateTimeEditSystem->setDateTime( QDateTime::currentDateTime() );
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

This is actually very easy to do.  The reason why the code was not updating was due to the lack of a slot declaration in the mainwindow.h file.  Here is the complete contents of the mainwindow.h header.

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

 private slots:
     void updateTime();

};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to use a timer?

Comment: Thanks, RA.  Do you mean that a timer is perhaps the most reliable way of doing this in Qt?  I have more experience using wxWidgets than Qt.

Comment: Yes, a timer should be reliable enough, especially if you only need it to update roughly once per second.  Qt even has a couple of examples: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/widgets-digitalclock.html  and  http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/widgets-shapedclock.html

Comment: OK, I will check it out. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, RA. This works really well, as I show in the code above.  Maybe you could post a brief answer to this question so that I can close it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Automatically updating a `QDateTimeEdit` or any other clock widget within Qt is easily accomplished with a `QTimer`.  Refer to the following examples for how to accomplish this:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/widgets-digitalclock.html

OR

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/widgets-shapedclock.html

Note that the resolution of a `QTimer` varies on different operating systems, but for updates that need to occur ~1 second at a time, a `QTimer` should be fine on virtually all platforms.  Refer to the following for more information on the resolution of `QTimer`:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/QTimer.html#accuracy-and-timer-resolution

Comment: Thank you, RA.  I had the notion that perhaps this could be automated with the use of signals and slots, but without the use of a timer. Using a timer, it is much simpler than what I had imagined (provided that the slot function is listed in the header file). As a C++ veteran, I am forgetting that Qt is pre-processed C++.